# alternate figures and text in a frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize, overlays

I am trying to alternate two figures and text in one frame. (I can get it to work if I only alternate one figure and the text, or the two figures.) Here's what I have tried -- not working. The code below alternates the two figures, but the frame ends before the remaining items are shown.

What am I doing wrong? What's the elegant way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

% use top alignment so that the first item does not move            
\begin{frame}[t]{My frame}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item Show first item in all slides (don't move it!)
        
        \alt<1-2>{
            \only<1>{
                \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight]{figureA}
                
                {\scriptsize Figure A in slide 1 only}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight]{figureB}
                
                {\scriptsize Figure B in slide 2 only}
            }
        }{
            \item<3-> This item in slides 3 and 4
            \item<4-> This item in slide 4, and good bye
        }            
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to do. Do you want image A (slide 1) to be replaced by a text (slide 2) and then replaced by image B (slide 3) and then replaced by another text (slide 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was to do `\item<1-4>` in the first item. Surely there must be a neater way of doing is, I'd still be curious to know how.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

% use top alignment so that the first item does not move            
\begin{frame}[t]{My frame}

\begin{itemize}
    
    \item<1-4> Show first item in all slides (don't move it!)
    
    \alt<1-2>{
        \only<1>{
            \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight]{figureA}
            
            {\scriptsize Figure A in slide 1 only}
        }
        \only<2>{
            \includegraphics[height=.75\textheight]{figureB}
            
            {\scriptsize Figure B in slide 2 only}
        }
    }{
        \item<3-> This item in slides 3 and 4
        \item<4-> This item in slide 4, and good bye
    }            
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```